# What is the equivalent function of PHP `time()` in swift?

Tags: swift, time

What is the equivalent function of PHP `time()` in swift?

I have used NSDate but its not like `time()` of PHP.

```
let now = NSDate()
print(now)
```

Comment: What does php's time() return?

Comment: You can use NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 to get the seconds since 1970

Comment: @MikeG can you post your answer?Without a decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the number of seconds that have passed since 1970 you can call:

```
var secondsSince1970 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

If you want this to return an integer you can use:

```
var secondsSince1970 = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

@thefredelment's answer is more complete.

Comment: Thank a lot for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use an NSDateFormatter instance to customize the display of an NSDate object, or even build an NSDate instance.

```
let myDateFomratter = NSDateFormatter()
myDateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

myDateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

This is just a really quick example, NSDateFormatter is an awesome class with a ton of flexibility. Check out the docs on it.

Edit, here's the class ref:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/

You can even choose from predefined date & time styles as well as ensure it matches whatever locale the user is in.

If you need seconds since 1970 as @MikeG suggested use:

NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

You can use NSDateFormatter to create a date from a string and then get a value like this or even build a date using a formatter and NSDateComponents, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/

Here is how you can get the interval from epoch without a decimal and then use it as a date:

```
let aDate = (NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 as NSNumber).integerValue

NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(aDate))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :D

Comment: time() in php does not contains decimal point. while timeIntervalSince1970 contains five decimal points.

Comment: Updated the answer with converting the timeInterval to an NSNumber, getting it's integer value and then using that to create a new Date object if you'd like, if not the aDate declaration is just an Int representing whole units of NSTimeIntervals (which are just Doubles).